# CSS div challenge: setting div height to another div; Aligning div to bottom of containing div - without absolute positioning

Tags: html, css

I have a required layout to construct and it is turning out to be much harder than what I thought to accomplish it.  I included a diagram showing how it needs to look.  My task seems simple enough, but I can't get it right.  The biggest issue is getting div D to align to the bottom of div A ***without*** using absolute positioning (that messes up my page).  Also related to this would be the need to make div A's height equal to div B's height, even when there is less content in it compared to the content in div B.

My diagram:
http://tinypic.com/r/sxln60/8

HTML:

```
<div class="container">

<div class="A">
<div class="C">Align to top</div>
<div class="D">Align to bottom</div>
</div><!--end A-->

<div class="B">
<img src="images/picture.jpg"/>
</div><!--end B-->

</div><!--end container-->
```

CSS:

```
.container {border: 1px solid #999; width:49%; box-sizing:border-box;  display: inline-block; padding: 20px; vertical-align: top;} /*This container is an inline element with another neighboring inline-block element*/
.A {width:39%; display:inline-block; vertical-align: top;}
.C {font-size: 1.5em;}
.B {width:60%; display:inline-block; vertical-align: top;}
.D {font-size: 1.2em;}
```

This is somewhat of a challenge.  Hopefully someone can rise to it.  I certainly can't.  I understand that these are not brand new topics, but they seem to be a unique combination of them in one task.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: is flexbox an option? you could use that.

Comment: This is a fairly good attempt at a first question, but I would recommend inserting the diagram and utilizing the code snippet feature next time as a convenience to others. Also provide more info about browser support requirements.

Comment: Thanks - yes I wasn't aware of the code snippet feature - that is an awesome feature that I will use next time.  Regarding the diagram, it would not allow me to insert an image until I clocked up 10 points, so I had no choice.  Re browser support:  All modern browsers for the last 2-3 years.  Don't care about the really old ones.  I will have a pop-up telling people to update if their browser is old.

Comment: If you're targeting browsers in no more than 3 years old, then you can safely use flex-box, and I recommend it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Use flex-box

If you don't need legacy browser support, you can safely *and quite effectively* use flex-box.

### .A height = .B height

Set `.container` to `display: flex;`. Now it is a flex container and `.A` and `.B` automatically become flex items.

On `.container`, set `align-items: stretch;` to make `.A` and `.B` stretch to fill the container.

There are additional flex properties that can be declared for more control. I have included them below for your reference, but most of them are just set to their default values.

```
.container {

    /* Flex container properties */
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    align-items: stretch;
    align-content: flex-start;
    justify-content: space-between;

    width: 50%;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 3px solid #999;
}
```

*Note: The flex spec has changed over recent time and has varied greatly among browsers. You will need to prefix and include the old syntax to cover the last couple versions of each major browser. See: [Prefixing Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/#flexbox-sass) in [A Complete Guide to Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) at [css-tricks.com](https://css-tricks.com)*

### .C align to top, .D align to bottom

Vertical positioning is where flex-box really saves the day.

Simply make `.A` a flex container, too (an element can be both a flex item and a flex container at the same time). Set `flex-direction: column;` and `justify-content: space-between;`.

Now `.C` and `.D` are flex items that will be evenly distributed from top to bottom: first item is on the top, last item on the bottom; and if you had other items, they'd be evenly distributed between.

```
.A {

    /* Flex container properties */
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;

    overflow: hidden;
    width: 40%;
    border: 3px solid cyan;
}
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container {
  
    /* Flex container properties */
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    align-items: stretch;
    align-content: flex-start;
    justify-content: space-between;
  
    padding: 20px;
    border: 3px solid #999;
}
.A {
  
    /* Flex container properties */
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
  
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 40%;
    border: 3px solid cyan;
}
.B {
    width: 60%;
    border: 3px solid magenta;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.C {
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    border: 3px solid yellow;
}
.D {
    font-size: 1.2em;
    border: 3px solid black;
}

/* Flex box prefixes */
.container {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -webkit-flex-direction: row;
        -ms-flex-direction: row;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: nowrap;
        -ms-flex-wrap: nowrap;
    -webkit-box-align: stretch;
    -webkit-align-items: stretch;
        -ms-flex-align: stretch;
    -webkit-align-content: flex-start;
        -ms-flex-line-pack: start;
    -webkit-box-pack: justify;
    -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
        -ms-flex-pack: justify;
}
.A {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
        -ms-flex-direction: column;
    -webkit-box-pack: justify;
    -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
        -ms-flex-pack: justify;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="A">
    <div class="C">C: Align to top<br /></div>
    <div class="D">D: Align to bottom</div>
  </div>
  <div class="B">
    B: <img src="http://placehold.it/300x200" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for going to so much effort to provide great answers.  I can see that you rate the flex-box solution highly, so I will give that one a go.  One question though...if the user happens to have a legacy browser and I have used a flex box solution, what will be displayed?  Do the divs still remain intact, but are simply not aligned properly?  Is there a way to code in a fallback solution using 'regular' CSS?  Thanks again.  You really have been a huge help.  Much appreciated.

Comment: Any browser that doesn't support flex will simply ignore it and will fallback to a previous declaration or default value. To conditionally declare float, margin, or other properties, there are a variety of methods, but that is beyond the scope of your original question and I encourage you to research the topics of "graceful degradation", "progressive enhancement", "conditional stylesheets", "feature detection". If this answer solves your problem please up vote and/or accept it. Then pay it forward by voting, commenting & answering other questions. :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Getting div **D** to align to the bottom of div **A** should be relatively straightforward, unless I'm missing something. Try adding the following rule to the **.D** selector -
   `margin-bottom: 1px;`
   Since div **D** is nested inside div **A**, its bottom margin will always be 1px above the bottom margin of div **A**.
2. Anytime you see two columns side by side on a page that you want to be of equal height, use the `display: table` rule. This rule allows one to represent data in the form of a table. Note that if you want to display data that is *tabular in its very essence*, you should use a `table` element.
   Anyway, getting back to our equal heights of A and B problem, restructure your HTML so that it allows your data to be represented in tabular form.

   ```
   <div class="tableContainer">
       <div class="tableRow">
           <div class="A">
               <div class="C">Align to top</div>
               <div class="D">Align to bottom</div>
           </div>

           <div class="B">
               <img src="images/picture.jpg"/>
           </div>
       </div>
   </div>
   ```

Here, the outermost div represents your entire table. Every div within the outermost div represents a row within the table. Every div within a row div represents a column within that row. **The beauty is that columns in a row are of equal height!**

Here's the corresponding CSS (with borders enabled, so that you can confirm the heights yourself.

```
.tableContainer {border: 1px solid #999; width:49%; box-sizing:border-box;  display: table; padding: 20px; vertical-align: top;} /*This container is an inline element with another neighboring inline-block element*/
.tableRow {display: table-row;}
.A {width:39%; display:table-cell; vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid;}
.C {font-size: 1.5em;border: 1px solid;}
.B {width:60%; display:table-cell; vertical-align: top;border: 1px solid;}
.D {font-size: 1.2em;border: 1px solid;margin-bottom: 1px;}
```

A good article on table displays is available [here](http://www.onenaught.com/posts/201/use-css-displaytable-for-layout).

Comment: That's not how `margin-bottom: 1px;` will affect `.D`.

Comment: Care to explain how it works then @gfullam? I'm a newbie as well, so my understanding of the way this works may not be complete yet.

Comment: Sure. `margin` sets the amount of space around an element, but won't affect its relative position until it runs into another element. In your example, adding `margin-bottom: 1px` would just add 1px of space to the bottom of `.D` and wouldn't affect its position since the margin won't come in contact with another element. The behavior you describe where `.D` "will always be 1px above the bottom margin of div A" is typically achieved with `position: absolute` and `bottom: 1px` (not `margin-bottom`).

Comment: @gfullam I think I understand now how margins work; they provide spatial boundaries between elements on a page. However, as long as the D div is the last nested element within the A div, won't `margin-bottom` ensure that D is always near the bottom of A?

Comment: No. It just means that if `.D` is pushed down to the bottom of `.A` that there will always be ''at least'' 1px of margin between the bottom of `.D` and the bottom of `.A`.

Comment: Oh, makes sense now :)

Answer (score 0):

A non-flex-box quasi-solution for legacy browsers.

For a superior solution using flex-box, see [my other answer on this page](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29013434/2502532).

---

### .A height = .B height

Set `.container` to `display: table;` and `.A` and `.B` to `display: table-cell;`. Tables automatically render cell heights the same according to the height of the tallest cell.

### .C align to top, .D align to bottom

This feat requires quite the rigmarole — and it is precisely the sort of problem that [flex-box](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) aims to solve. But I will show you a non-flex-box solution since I don't know what legacy browser support you require.

Float `.C` and give it `width: 100%` as well as `padding-bottom: 100%` and countering negative `margin-bottom`.

Then give `.D` a 100% `padding-top` to push it down.

In combination, this adds a little extra height to the cell, but it is the best you can achieve without flex-box or absolute positioning; and it allows both divs to have dynamic height.

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 20px;
    vertical-align: top;
    border: 3px solid #999;
}
.A {
    display: table-cell;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 40%;
    border: 3px solid cyan;
}
.B {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 60%;
    vertical-align: top;
    border: 3px solid magenta;
}
.C {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: -100%;
    padding-bottom: 100%;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    border: 3px solid yellow;
}
.D {
    padding-top: 100%;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    border: 3px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="A">
    <div class="C">C: Align to top</div>
    <div class="D">D: Align to bottom</div>
  </div>
  <div class="B">
    B: <img src="http://placehold.it/300x200" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks gfullam for your detailed response, much appreciated.  Just a couple of questions....I have used display:inline-block wherever I can on my page layout because I'm avoiding floats altogther.  Is there a way to align D to bottom without using a float or absolute positioning?   Also, will the browser interpret display:table as tabular data, or do we just get the structural benefits without the assumption of tabular data?  Just thinking of SEO here.

Comment: That's a really loaded comment: 1. Don't avoid floats altogether. They're not inherently bad, just often misused. 2. Don't avoid absolute positioning altogether either. Likewise, it's not inherently bad and there are times when it makes sense to use; that's why it exists. 3. There is no implication to the browser or search engines that `display: table` equates to tabular data. CSS is for presentation only, not semantics. Using <table> markup does imply tabular data. 4. The CSS landscape was paved on the creative exploitation of whatever works.